# Get Typescript object from Jest mock

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I am trying to test a particular scenario with help of jest.

`SomeClient` is exported as a non default class from the `some/module` and has a constructor and one of the methods like

`SomeClient(string endpoint, string token)` and `getProperties(): Promise<Properties>`

`ConnectivityManager` has a method `isConnected` whose signature is like

`public static async isConnected(someClient: SomeClient): Promise<boolean>` which also calls `someClient.getProperties()`

In test class `ConnectivityManager.test.ts` my code is like this

```
import { SomeClient } from 'some/module';

jest.mock('some/module', () => {
      return {
        SomeClient: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
          return {
            getProperties: (): Promise<Properties> =>
              new Promise((resolve) => {
                resolve(mockResponseObject);
              })
          };
        })
      };
    });

test('isConnected should be able to return true if SomeClient returns Properties', async () => {
  const result = await ConnectivityManager.isConnected(someClientMock); 
  //someClientMock how do I get the mock object of type SomeClient to pass here?
}
```

How do I get the mock object of type `SomeClient` to pass to `ConnectivityManager.isConnected`?

Comment: `const someClientMock = new SomeClient(....);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to have such a complex way of mocking if your ConnectivityManager.isConnected uses only the SomeClient.getProperties.

You can do the following:

```js
import { SomeClient } from 'some/module';

test('isConnected should be able to return true if SomeClient returns Properties', async () => {
  //setup
  const someClientMock = { getProperties: () => Promise.resolve(mockResponseObject) } as any as SomeClient;
  //act
  const result = await ConnectivityManager.isConnected(someClientMock); 
  //assert
  expect(result).toBe(true);
}
```